# How to Generate div Elements from Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: html, excel, file-conversion

What's the best way to go from a table or excel spreadsheet to div elements? I have table that has a couple hundred rows that I want to represent as div elements in a HTML file. The finished product will look something like this:

```
<div id="COL1" style="display:none;">COL2 blah blah COL3</div>
```

The text between COL2 and COL3 will all be the same. I can just as easily insert it into my table before converting. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you planning on using a script to do this or are you doing it by hand?

Comment: Definitely not by hand

Comment: OK, you could do this with nearly any kind of scripting language - got a favorite?

Comment: javascript is the only thing I know.

Comment: Use this to convert a CSV file to Javascript array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1293163/1270996 Then loop through the array to generate your HTML. - NOTE: with a good link this time.

Comment: you linked to this page

Comment: Sorry, dumb question. How do you get from a table to comma separated values?

Comment: In Excel, File->Save As->CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the input correctly, but if you want to generate a bunch of `DIV`s with some repeating text, you may add to `E1` (assuming your text `COL1...3` and `blah blah` are placed in columns `A:D` starting first row) the following formula:

```
="<div id="""&A1&""" style="""&"display:none;"""&">"&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&"</div>"
```

Autofill it down the list of text values and export / copy to HTML editor generated `DIV`s.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd52pp2p34flesg/DIVgenerator.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript/jquery or whatever scripting language you are familiar with.

First step will be getting the data from excel sheet into an array and then you can append it
in the html using

```
var i=0;
$.each(array, function () {
$("#DIVID").append(array[i]);
i++;
});
```

this will basically iterate through each element in the array[].